# Sending xlsx file using SMTP & Python 3

Tags: python, excel, smtp, smtplib

I'm having trouble getting the SMTP server to keep my filenames as I attach them to emails and send them.  I ran this twice, and it worked perfectly.  The name and excel sheet showed as they were supposed to.  Now, no matter what I do, the attachment is always something like ATT00001.xlsx  when it used to work just fine.  (literally left for lunch break and re-ran it when I got back with no changes)  I'm wondering if it's how i'm attaching the excel sheet to my email.  Would anyone happen to know what's going on with this?  Thanks!

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
sender='email@email.org'
recipients='email@recipient.org'
server=smtplib.SMTP('mail.server.lan')

msg['Subject']='Quarterly Summary'
msg['From']=sender
msg['To']=recipients



filename = r'C:\Users\user.chad\Quarterly\project\output\MyData.xlsx'
attachment = open(r'C:\Users\user.chad\Quarterly\project\output\MyData.xlsx', 'rb')
xlsx = MIMEBase('application','vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
xlsx.set_payload(attachment.read())

encoders.encode_base64(xlsx)
xlsx.add_header('Content-Dispolsition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
msg.attach(xlsx)

server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
attachment.close()
```

Comment: are you sure it is Content-dispolsition?
I have something like:

            with open(attachment, "rb") as attach:
                part = MIMEApplication(
                    attach.read(),
                    Name=os.path.basename(attachment)
                )
                part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(
                    os.path.basename(attachment))
                msg.attach(part)

Comment: @E.Serra duuuuuuude. spelling error.  Thank you.  If you post this as an answer i'll give you credit.

Comment: no problem mate, happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record:

```
xlsx.add_header('Content-Dispolsition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
```

should be

```
xlsx.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to add an attachment with text/html conent.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

message = MIMEMultipart()

# add text
message.attach(
    MIMEText(
        content,
        'html',
        'utf-8'
        )
    )

# add attachment
attachment = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
# open a file to attach
attachment.set_payload(open(filepath, "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % self.filename )
message.attach(attachment)


server.sendmail(SENDER, receivers, message.as_string())
```